# Alternative to BitConverter.ToInt32

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitconverter

I'm using `BitConverter.ToInt32` to pack 3 `byte` values into an `int`, like so:

```
byte R = 0;
byte G = 0;
byte B = 0;
int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(new byte[] { R, G, B, 0 }, 0);
```

Is there a faster way to do this that doesn't involve the creation of a new `int` each time?  Getting the bytes out of an `int` is easy:

```
int i = 34234;
byte B = (byte)(i >> 0);
byte G = (byte)(i >> 8);
byte R = (byte)(i >> 16);
```

Is there a simple way to reverse this process and use bit-shifting to write the RGB bytes back over an existing `int`?

Comment: Why are you worried about the creation of a new `int`? Creating an `int` is free. The part to be concerned about is creation of a new `byte[]` every time.

Comment: @gabe: this is just sample code. In the real code, I was assigning to a pre-instantiated class-level byte array. Creating an int is virtually free, but not if you're doing this for hundreds of 320 x 240 arrays. The bit-shifting is significantly faster than BitConverter.ToInt32.

Comment: You're convoluting RGB and BGR here (the two code snippets do not round-trip).

Comment: Creating an int isn't "virtually" free -- it's completely free. BitConverter isn't slow. Putting the bytes into the array and making the functino call is what's slow.

Comment: I finally did some benchmarking on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326125/faster-way-converter-byte-array-to-int/4331638#4331638 It seems that the function call overhead of `BitConverter` is fairly significant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int i = (B << 0) | (G << 8) | (R << 16);
```

Comment: Shifting by 0 is not really necessary.

Comment: Love the Lemmings avatar, by the way. I think I mentioned that before.

Comment: @IVlad: But it makes the code much better to read, at no cost.

Comment: This undoes the bit-shifting shown, which is in BGR(A) format.  But it isn't equivalent to the BitConverter snippet, which uses RGB(A) format.

Answer (score 4):

You ought to consider the [Color structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx).  It has R, G and B properties and FromArgb() and ToArgb() methods.

Comment: You'd think `Color` would be ideal for this, but it's piggishly slow.

Comment: Hard to see how it could be, it uses simple shifts, and and or, just like regular code.

Comment: I can confirm Musi's findings. Color.FromRgb is even slower than the BitConverter.